# Disqus API to parse thread message

Tags: api, disqus

I am trying to parse a thread message through the Disqus API with no success. This is my call in a php script:

```
$endpoint = 'http://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/details.json?api_key='.urlencode($apikey).'&forum='.$shortname.'&thread='.urlencode($thread);
```

What I get is a .json packed with information but without very body of the posted message.

I get the same result if I change the method `details.json` to `list.json`.

If I call `listThreads.json` I get a .json with the following line

```
{"code": 3, "response": "Endpoint resource not valid"}
```

If I call `listPosts.json` I get

```
{"cursor": {"prev": null, "hasNext": false, "next": "0:0:0", "hasPrev": false, "total": null, "id": "0:0:0", "more": false}, "code": 0, "response": []}
```

(This specific post has no comments)

Comment: Happy to help, what are you expecting when you say "Thread message"? Would that be the content of the article itself (which we don't pull currently), or something else?